# Why is (await import("node:process")).on undefined?

Tags: node.js

Title says it all.

Running

```js
console.log((await import("node:process")).on)
```

Results in `undefined` being printed.

Why is this the case?

If I use a static import, it works as expected:

```js
import process from "node:process"

console.log(process.on)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static import declaration is a default import, short for

```
import { default as process } from "node:process"
console.log(process.on)
```

The corresponding dynamic import would be

```
const { default: process } = await import("node:process");
console.log(process.on)
```

or

```
console.log((await import("node:process")).default.on)
```

Comment: Oh, of course! Thanks ‍♂️ not the first time this has bitten me.